# angular service is throwing error when called in controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn angular. i have written below piece of code but this is throwing error as service.getImages is not a function. Please help me figure out what i am missing here.

service :

```
services.service('interiors', function($http){

    return{
        getImages : function(){
            return $http.get("imageListSpace/living?from=300000&to=200000&page=1");
        }
    }

});
```

Controller :

```
otCtrls.controller('ImageListController', [ '$scope', '$routeParams', 'interiors', function($scope, $routeParams, interiors) {
            $scope.imageList = {};

            interiors.getImageList().success(function(data) {
                $scope.imageList = data;
            });
} ]);
```

View :

```
<li ng-repeat="image in imageList | filter:query">
        <div id="imageContainer" >
            <img src="{{image.path_small}}" />
            <div id="imageText">
                <p>{{image.description_short}}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="priceText">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <span>Starting from </span><span>Rs {{image.price}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

        </div>
    </li>
```

Please help me to figure out what i am missing here.

Comment: You're calling getImageList from your controller but your service function is called getImages

Comment: Also, $scope.imageList should be an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and service have different names for the same function either change your service to be

```
return{
    getImageList : function(){
        return $http.get("imageListSpace/living?from=300000&to=200000&page=1");
    }
}
```

or your controller to call

```
interiors.getImages().success(function(data) {
            $scope.imageList = data;
        });
```